# Setting does not get removed?

Tags: c#, listview, listbox, selecteditem

I have both a ListBox (`AlarmBox`) and a ListView (`listView1`). They both save into 2 different Properties.Settings (`AlarmList` and `AlarmList2`).

```
Properties.Settings.Default.AlarmList.Remove(AlarmList.SelectedItem);
Properties.Settings.Default.AlarmList2.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems);
AlarmList.Items.RemoveAt(AlarmList.SelectedIndices[0]);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);
```

That's the code for the remove button, but since listView1 doesn't have a `SelectedItem` function, I resorted to using `SelectedItems`.

When removing an item from both boxes, `AlarmBox` removes the values correctly from both the application and the settings, but when removing from `listView1`, the value is only removed from the app, but isn't removed from the settings.

**EDIT:**
Also, when replacing `listView1.SelectedItems` with `AlarmList.SelectedItem`, it removes correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
```

OK, then how about trying the RemoveAt with the index?

```
.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't refer to AlarmBox at all in the sample code, only to AlarmList.
Is it correct to be referencing listView1, or should you be referring to AlarmList2 instead?

At a glance, it looks a bit mixed up...

Glad it's solved! I should have refreshed before posting!